# Passing an DB Connection to another Class

Tags: python

I have two classes, one uses selenium to browse the internet, and the other inserts data into a mysql database.

```
class DBConnection:
    def __init__(self, db_host=DB_HOST, db_port=DB_PORT, db_user=DB_USER, db_password=DB_PASSWORD, db_name=DB_NAME):
        self.host = DB_HOST
        self.port = DB_PORT
        self.name = DB_NAME
        self.user = DB_USER
        self.password = DB_PASSWORD
        self.conn = None
        self.cursor = None

class WebDriver:
    def __init__(self, download_folder=DOWNLOAD_FOLDER):
        self.driver = False

    def start_webdriver(self):
        """
        Initiate a Firefox profile for Selenium WebDriver.
        """
        fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

What would be the best way to get a db connection from the WebDriver class? Would something like this work?

```
class WebDriver:
    def __init__(self, download_folder=DOWNLOAD_FOLDER):
        self.driver = False
        self.download_folder = download_folder
        self.last_payment = None
        self.DBConnection = DBConnection()
        self.DBConnection.get_conn()
        self.DBConnection.get_cursor()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starts, you are initializing DBConnection wrong! Should be

```
class DBConnection(object):
    def __init__(self, db_host=DB_HOST, db_port=DB_PORT, db_user=DB_USER, db_password=DB_PASSWORD, db_name=DB_NAME):
        self.host = db_host    # lower case!
        self.port = db_port
        self.name = db_name
        self.user = db_user
        self.password = db_password
```

then you can allow the user to specify settings like so:

```
class WebDriver(object):
    def __init__(self, download_folder=DOWNLOAD_FOLDER, **kwargs):
        self.driver = False
        self.download_folder = download_folder
        self.last_payment = None
        self.DBConnection = DBConnection(**kwargs)
        self.DBConnection.get_conn()
        self.DBConnection.get_cursor()
```

Comment: Thank you, what would be an example of a `kwarg` that a user might pass to the DBConnection?

Comment: `wd = WebDriver(db_host='192.168.0.5', db_port=3401)`